# how to display related node titles to taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I want to display list of taxonomy terms and besides each taxonomy term need to display represented node title as well. For suppose To X taxonomy term a,b,c are taxonomy child terms. I have created a page and selected b term. Now I want to display in the below o/p.

```
>  X
>        a
>        b -> <node title>
>        c
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be to use a taxonomy view using the views module and in the view add a relationship the content type where the terms are use. To finish you can display the results as an HTML list grouping by the parent term.